# I am looking for a children's fantasy book with a tribe of raven or crow people

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

I am looking for a children's fantasy book with a tribe of raven or crow people. They actually grew feathers from their skins. A preteen boy fell in love with a regular girl. I'm pretty sure she was Asian but his family kept telling him it could not work out between them. I read this book in 2004 - 2005 ish. Does this sound familiar to anyone?

Comment: Tengu are a fairly common trope (they even have their own [TV Tropes page](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Tengu)).  Likewise, teen "inappropriate romance" is incredibly common.  Do you have any more information you can share with us?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly the prequel to the Maximum Ride series by James Patterson. When the wind blows

The comment about the Asian girl made me think of it - there is one in the novel who one of the other bird kids has a crush on

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/When_the_Wind_Blows_(Patterson_novel)